# Curl to Advanced rest Client

Tags: json, rest, google-chrome, jakarta-ee, curl

i need to send below curl command using rest client

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
 \ -H "Authorization: Basic MzUzYjMwMmM0NDU3NGY1NjUwNDU2ODdlNTM0ZTdkNmE6Mjg2OTI0Njk3ZTYxNWE2NzJhNjQ2YTQ5MzU0NTY0NmM="
 \ -d '{"user":{"emailAddress":"test@example.com"}, "password":"password"}'
 \ 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2-provider/v1.0/users'
```

[image]

so far i have managed to put it like above screen but im not sure how to 
put

```
-d '{"user":{"emailAddress":"test@example.com"}, "password":"password"}'
```

in rest client

Comment: Did you try simply putting `{"user":{"emailAddress":"test@example.com"}, "password":"password"}` in the raw data box?

Comment: yes but it didnt work

Comment: i have put it on header as well as in payload ection

Comment: Other than that, I don't see any difference, except that the base64 is missing the `=` at the end (which makes a difference)

Answer (score 3):

there is a section below for "payload"
that is where the json that you have should be placed.

the "-H" content is for the header
the "-d" is for the contents (body)

and for what its worth, the industry standard has been moving towards postman as a common chrome plugin/tool instead of advanced rest client, but to each their own.